# how to prevent Dynamic content overlapped on header and footer in React-to-print package

Tags: css, reactjs, react-to-print

I have an issue that the dynamic HTML content is overwriting on the header and footer. dynamic content is coming from the response of API and I have shown in the component but while printing this PDF the dynamic content is overlapped on the header and footer. I have used a react-to-print library and the content is dynamic and it has multiple pages. suggest me a strong solution for this. I want the Header and footer along with content but the content shouldn't overlap on the header and footer and the remaining content should go to the next page.

I have rendered data from the response of API through renderHTML() function.

```
RenderHTML=()=>{
    const htmlPart= this.state.carfaxHTML
      return(
        <div className="rendercarfexHtmlData" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: htmlPart} } />
      )
  }

<div className="row page-break-top">  <div className="col-sm-12">   
    <Card>
         <CardBody className="p-0">
           <div className="newFormatReport">
             <ReportHeaderIraq />
               <div className="container text-main-heading mt-0 p-0" id="carfax_html">
                  <div className="row mt-0">
                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                      {this.RenderHTML()}
                    </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               <ReportFooterIraq />
              </div>
            </CardBody>
           </Card>
          </div>
         </div>
```

this is the rendering part where the function is called.

```
<ReactToPrint
                trigger={() => {
                  return (
                      <button className="glass btn btn-lg btn-danger pull-right">
                        <i className="fa fa-print" />
                        &nbsp; {this.lang("Print PDF")}
                      </button>
                  );
                }}
                content={() => this.componentRef}
              />
```

From here React-to-print is triggered.

Comment: Show some of your code and how you tried to solve it. Without context this is impossible to handle.

Comment: Thanks for your helping hands ivo I have attached an image that dangerously sets HTML. Actually, I have set the response of API in the state named carFaxHtml and then shows it in <div>. I have called this function inside render().

Comment: Now check it I have attached the required code to analyze the issue.

Comment: can anybody suggest me a solution! it's a vital to solve this issue. Kindly inform me if anybody knows anything

Comment: @DhavalPrajapati do you have the answer for this?